# Data access: Trying to get access through localhost

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, rest

I am currently developing an application through xamarin forms. In this application it is necessary to use a backend solution. In able to simulate this I have created a rest api using EF core as an in-memory data provider.  The rest api functions just fine, and I have used postman to test this.

My goal is then to display the information from this rest api to my iphone simulator. I have set up an listview in my xaml file, and am trying to access my data through my code behind file:

```
public partial class testing_backendPage : ContentPage
{
    private const string Url = "http://localhost:5000/user/";
    private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    private ObservableCollection<Post> _posts; 

    public testing_backendPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
        var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(content);
        _posts = new ObservableCollection<Post>(posts);
        postsListView.ItemsSource = _posts; 
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

When I run the program, everything runs just fine, however the data is not displayed.

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the line of `var content` and share us the error message

Comment: I had the same problem. I resolved it in two ways: I changed the `Url` with a public `Url` on my dev server; I added a `ViewModel` and in it I read data. If you need more info...

Comment: @prtdomingo added breakpoint, however found no error message. Is it possible to read the current values some how?

Comment: @Enrico how do you pass the data to your xaml file. I first tried using lisview, but no data occurred, then tried using label, however only the name of the class shows, and not the actual content. Any Idea?